# Как во Flutter использовать шестнадцатиричную форму отображения цвета?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-ui

Мне нравится работать с цветом в шестнадцатиричной форме, с помощью строк вида `#RRGGBB` (Например: `#DD23CE`).
Я привык к данной форме отображения цвета и считаю ее удобной.
Она используется в HTML/CSS, Photoshop'e, Figma, и пр. инструментах.
Используя её я могу не беспокоиться о корректном переносе дизайна из прототипов и макетов приложений.

Но, к большому сожалению, я не нашел способа работать с цветом в привычном мне формате.
При создании объекта цвета я могу указать только целое число, **ПРИЧЕМ ТОЛЬКО ОДНО**!
*(Как вообще можно передать информацию о всех составляющих компонентах цвета одним целым числом?)*

---

**Внимание, вопрос:**

- Есть ли способ во Flutter'e работать с цветом в шестнадцатиричном формате?
- Если нет, то есть ли способ преобразовать цвет из шестнадцатиричного формата?

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50081213/how-do-i-use-hexadecimal-color-strings-in-flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, к сожалению, во `Flutter` при создании объекта `Color` вы можете указать **только ОДНО целое число**, либо воспользоваться именованными конструкторами `fromARGB` и `fromRGBO` с передачей всех компонентов цвета (*все параметры также представлены в **целочисленном** формате*) и для вашей задачи формально необходимо преобразовать данную строку в одно целое число.

> Как вообще можно передать информацию о всех  составляющих компонентах цвета одним целым числом?

Отвечаю:
переменная `int` в `Dart` занимает 32 бита

- Биты **с 24 по 31** отвечают за значение **альфа-канала**(*прозрачности*).
- Биты **с 16 по 23** отвечают за значение **красной** составляющей.
- Биты **с 8 по 15** отвечают за значение **зеленой** составляющей.
- Биты **с 0 по 7** отвечают за значение **синей** составляющей.

> Разработчики Dart безусловно молодцы, что так ловно придумали способ хранения цвета в одном целочисленном значении, но как с этим жить мобильным разработчикам?

К счастью для простых разработчиков в Dart целые числа также могут использовать шестнадцатеричное представление. Они начинаются с префикса `0x` и выглядят следующим образом:

```dart
int hex = 0xDEAFBB03;
```

Что, согласитесь, очень похоже на то, что вы обычно используете при записи цвета в шестнадцатиричной форме. В данном случае только разрядов больше. Поэтому во `Flutter` при создании цвета нужно указывать не только
три составляющие цвета **RGB** (красный, зеленый, синий), **но и непрозрачность**.
Для корректного переноса цветов из формате RGB, непрозрачность всегда должна быть указана полная (255). В шестнадцатеричном формате это соответствует значению `FF`, которые должны быть указаны в первых двух разрядах.

Теперь нам просто нужно записать нашу цветовую строку следующим образом:

```dart
const color = const Color(0xffb74093); // Второй `const` при присваивании необязателен.
```

Буквы могут быть указаны как в нижнем, так и в верхнем регистре. (используйте то, что вам удобнее)

```dart
const color = const Color(0xFFB74093);
```

Если же Вы захотите указать непрозрачность отличную от полной, то вам придется самому перевести интенсивность данного канала в шестнадцатиричный формат либо же вы можете воспользоваться [данной таблицей](https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/8710f6f752f6a0f2cae13abb538f0e8e#hex-opacity-values) в качестве шпаргалки.(*для других каналов она также работает*)

#### Расширение класса

Начиная с Dart 2.6.0, вы можете создать расширение для класса Color, позволяющее использовать шестнадцатеричные цветовые строки для создания объекта Color:

```dart
extension HexColor on Color {
  /// Строка может иметь формат "aabbcc" или "ffaabbcc" с необязательным префиксом "#".
  static Color fromHex(String hexString) {
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    if (hexString.length == 6 || hexString.length == 7) buffer.write('ff');
    buffer.write(hexString.replaceFirst('#', ''));
    return Color(int.parse(buffer.toString(), radix: 16));
  }

  /// Флаг leadingHashSign, отвечающий за наличие знака решетки в начале по умолчанию равен `true`.
  String toHex({bool leadingHashSign = true}) => '${leadingHashSign ? '#' : ''}'
      '${alpha.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${red.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${green.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}'
      '${blue.toRadixString(16).padLeft(2, '0')}';
}
```

Метод `fromHex()` может быть объявлен как в расширении, так и в миксине или классе, потому что для его использования необходимо явно указать имя `HexColor`
Для метода `toHex()` же в свою очередь имеет смысл использовать именно расширение, которое можно использовать неявно.
**Например:**

```dart
void main() {
  final Color color = HexColor.fromHex('#aabbcc');

  print(color.toHex());
  print(const Color(0xffaabbcc).toHex());
}
```

#### Важное замечание (про переменные и константы)

Простота определения цветов из шестнадцатеричной строки может вызвать соблазн создавать их тут и там на лету, что в свою очередь может вызвать и негативный эффект.
В подавляющем большинстве материалов по Dart'у используются заранее определенные константы цветов. И это имеет смысл для приложений на Flutter'e с большим количеством виджетом и большим количеством цветов, соответственно...и что самое важное - с огромным количеством обращений к ним при отрисовке интерфейса.
Поверьте, постоянное обращение к одним и тем же участкам памяти на каждом кадре это не то чего вы бы хотели.
Работа с константами оптимизируется на этапе компиляции и работа с ними предпочтительнее, чем работа с переменными.

**Поэтому если Вы сами определяете цвета из шестнадцатиричной строки, то в идеале делайте это также, как показано на первых моих примерах, а именно с использованием констант.**

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50081214/4558866